# Primitive roots and orders

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $p$ is an odd prime and $r$ is a primitive root, I have proved that $p-1 | ord_{p^{2}} (r)$.

However, I am struggling to prove that if $r$ is $not$ a primitive root modulo $p^2$, then $ord_{p^{2}} (r) = p-1$. I have found an example of where this works.

If I set $p=5$, then $r=24$ is not a primitive root modulo $p^{2}=25$ and the order is $p-1=4$.

I am unsure of how to prove why $ord_{p^{2}} (r) = p-1$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\phi(p^2) = p \cdot (p - 1)$, so $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ is a group of order $p \cdot (p - 1)$. You have already proven that 
$$p - 1 \mid \text{ord}_{p^2}(r).$$
Hence there are only two possibilities: $\text{ord}_{p^2}(r) = p - 1$ or $\text{ord}_{p^2}(r) = p \cdot (p - 1)$.

Comment: Which part of this relates to the fact that $r$ is not a primitive root? Thanks for your response

Comment: Note that saying that $r$ is not a primitive root modulo $p^2$ is the same as saying that $\text{ord}_{p^2}(r) \neq p \cdot (p - 1)$, so this only leaves the first option.

Comment: I thought that $ p-1 | ord_{p^{2}} (r)$ relied on the assumption that $r$ is a primitive root

Comment: That is correct, the fact that $p - 1 \mid \text{ord}_{p^2}(r)$ relies on the assumption that $r$ is a primitive root modulo $p$. The assumption that $r$ is not a primitive root modulo $p^2$ then gives  $\text{ord}_{p^2}(r) \neq p \cdot (p - 1)$, leaving only one possibility: $\text{ord}_{p^2}(r) = p - 1$

Comment: I don't understand how you can deduce that the $ord_{p^{2}} (r) = p-1$ for when $r$ is not a primitive root, when the $p-1 | ord_{p^{2}} (r)$ is based on the assumption that $r$ is a primitive root.

Comment: There are two different notions of being a primitive root for $r$ that we are dealing with here: namely $r$ being a primitive root modulo $p$ and primitive root modulo $p^2$. In my post I am assuming that $r$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ but NOT a primitive root modulo $p^2$. This gives the conclusion that $\text{ord}_{p^2}(r) = p - 1$.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't take in consideration the different cases for $r$ being a primitive root modulo $p$ or $p^2$. Thanks a lot for your time and effort!